What is the difference between "Hot Corners" and "Hot Corner Shortcuts"?
What is the difference between "Accessibility -> Hot Corners" and "Desktop & Dock -> Hot Corner Shortcuts"?

Accessibility > Hot Corners
This is for people who need special accommodations, such as people unable to use their hands. In the setting description it states:

Pick the one-off action to be performed after dwelling on a screen corner

Emphasis mine

You can see right below that "Dwelling" allows people needing special accommodations to use the pointer:

Dwell allows the pointer to be controlled using head- or eye-tracking technology.

So when people using this feature holds the pointer on a corner, the selected action will be triggered.
Desktop & Dock > Hot Corner Shortcuts
This setting is to trigger shortcuts, such as lock screen, trigger screen saver, launch Launchpad, etc. if the mouse is brought to one of the corners of your screen.

Dwelling is basically for people who cannot use their arms and use their eyes or heads instead for moving the mouse. So one setting is more oriented towards handless/armless people (with shortcuts to help them navigate menus - something unnecessary for people without such handicap), and the other one is just for regular shortcuts more widely used. The key difference is the audience and the shortcuts available.

Hmm, still dont get the difference. First one is "Dwelling" my mouse to the corner, the other one is "moving" my mouse to the corner? What is the difference?

@kerner1000 "Dwell allows the pointer to be controlled using head- or eye-tracking technology." Dwelling is basically for people who cannot use their arms and use their eyes or heads instead for moving the mouse. So one setting is more oriented towards handless/armless people (with shortcuts to help them navigate menus - something unnecessary for people without such handicap), and the other one is just for regular shortcuts more widely used. The key difference is the audience and the shortcuts available.
